# MySQL C++ Connector linking errors

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector, database-connection

I am trying to set up a connection to a MySQL database. The code compiles fine, but when linking I always get errors. I've tried both dynamic and static linking but nothing works. Some of the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::Error::Error(char const *)" (__imp_??0Error@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::check_type(enum mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::Type)const " (?check_type@Value@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@IBEXW4Type@1234@@Z)  DatabaseTest    

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::~DbDoc(void)" (__imp_??1DbDoc@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::~Value(void)" (??1Value@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@XZ) DatabaseTest    

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::DbDoc(void)" (__imp_??0DbDoc@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::Value(void)" (??0Value@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@XZ)   DatabaseTest     


#include <iostream>
#include "mysqlx/xdevapi.h"

int main()
{
    //short test, program doesn't compile, the headers aren't included here because they are more than 1000 lines long. You can get them at the MySQL homepage
    return 0;
}
```

I use the newest version of the connector. You can download the project [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nT3zSmgFLPR8I6AJftshoF5m3Jhuv_Bu) if you want to check the settings. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include **all** relevant code in your question post *as text*. Preferably, this will be a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Links such as the one you have provided may grow stale over time, and your question will be much less useful to future viewers.

Comment: Use the C library for MySQL.  I've had too many hassles trying to get the C++ compiling.  No issues so far with the C language interface.

Answer (score 0):

First, find where is your mysqlx directory is located, using following command:

```
sudo find / -name mysqlx
```

In Debian system, it is usually located in `/usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8/` .
For compiling, use folllowing command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8/ -lmysqlcppconn8 filename.cpp
```